# Exposing WebService on Mule

Tags: web-services, wsdl, mule

I wanted **expose an WebService on mule**  and its working.

- My concern is that am not sure if this is the right approach to follow in exposing a webservice.
- As I wanted to be able to view my Mule HTTP Inbound endpoint wsdl i.e

> XXX:8084/HelloService?wsdl

, notice the actual service is running on port **8085**.

```
 <flow name="WS_In" doc:name="WS_In">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8084/HelloService" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
        <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8085/HelloService?WSDL" payload="envelope" namespace="http://example.org/HelloService"  service="Hello"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>        

    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP" path="test"/>

</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're not *exposing* a service but just *proxying* it right?

Why not using the ready made pattern for that? See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Web+Service+Proxy+Pattern

Comment: Thanks for the response and link David, yes am just _proxying_ it.

Answer (score 0):

Proxying web services is a very common practice used for different reasons like security or auditing. This pattern allows a short and easy configuration of such a proxy.

With this you can

1. Transform the SOAP envelope (body or header) to add or remove specific entries.
2. Rewrite remote WSDLs so they appear to bind to services inside a corporate firewall.

Mule has already defined these proxy transformers in various ways:
Ref: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/web-service-proxy-pattern#wsdl-redirection